# How to use RouteConfig in Angular2 with plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I am building an app using Angular 2 with plain JavaScript and I can't find any example of how to use RouteConfig for JavaScript (not ts).

Can anyone give me an example of how to use.
I tried like this but it's not working:

```
(function(app) {
    app.MainComponent =
        ng.core.Component({
                selector: 'app',
                templateUrl: 'app/components/main/main.view.html'
            })
            .Class({
                constructor: function() {}
            })
            .RouteConfig([
                {path: '/', redirectTo: '/job'},
                {path: '/job', component: JobViewComponent }
            ])
    ;

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

And I have other file that is JobView

```
(function(app) {
    app.JobViewComponent =
        ng.core.Component({
                selector: 'job-view',
                templateUrl: 'app/components/job_view/job_view.view.html'
            })
            .Class({
                constructor: function() {}
            });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RouteConfig` is a decorator so you should use it this way:

```
app.MainComponent =
  ng.core.Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/main/main.view.html'
  })
  .Class({
    constructor: function() {}
  });

app.MainComponent = ng.core.RouteConfig([
  {path: '/', redirectTo: '/job'},
  {path: '/job', component: JobViewComponent }
])(app.MainComponent);
```

Here is a working plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZcSGHSsV8fBOc4TnI68h?p=preview.

Comment: I tried the plnkr version and it's working ok, but when i want to add  a second controller with a specific path I get this error: EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "click"   Here is the modified plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/FY1O5RiBRMhrA4tmryoS?p=preview

Comment: That's strange since I don't have the behavior with the `angular2-all.umd.dev.js` file :-( Seems to be a bug in the minified file...

Comment: Thanks. I will not use for now .min version. Hope will fix in the next release.

Comment: After updating to rc1 and use the new router I am getting this error: `ng.router.RouteConfig is not a function`. From ts doc it looks like it should be the same. Do you know why I am getting this error now? Thanks.